# Turn Sprite back to 0 degrees in Sprite Kit

Tags: sprite-kit

I have successfully turned the sprite 45 degrees now I need it to turn 45 degrees back to 0 degree, but the code below turns it so fast you cant even see it, so it doesnt look like its moving.

```
 SKAction *rotate = [SKAction rotateToAngle:M_PI_4 duration:0.1 shortestUnitArc:YES];
                    [actor runAction: rotate];
                    SKAction *rotate2 = [SKAction rotateToAngle:0 duration:0.1 shortestUnitArc:YES];
                    [actor runAction: rotate2];
```

How would I turn it to 45 degrees, then gradually turn back to 0?

Thanks!!!

Comment: use a sequence action, as is both actions will run simultaneously

Comment: Wow thank you for that. Brain fart...

Answer (score 0):

You need to sequence the actions like so:

```
[actor runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[rotate, rotate2]];
```

Comment: Oh gosh, didn't see that Steffen had already answered in the comment!